# Android: How to set a drawable as a windowSplashScreenBackground parameter in the new SplashScreen API?

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-theme

I want to make splash screen with gradient background and logo using [Splash Screen API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen)

Smth like this:

[image]

I`ve style with field `windowSplashScreenBackground` where value is solid color and it works fine:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyApp</item>
</style>
```

The attribute `windowSplashScreenBackground` can take only colors.

Any ideas how to create gradient background? May be smth like this:

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApp.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    ... 
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/gradient_splash_screen_background</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

Also I tried declare background in field `android:windowBackground` instead of `windowSplashScreenBackground`

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gradient_splash_screen_background</item>
<!--        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/purple</item>-->
<!--        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_layers</item>-->
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyApp</item>
</style>
```

But it solve one issue and consume another one. Background of screen accept gradient but logo become invisible

Comment: Yes correct, you can pass start, middle, end color with angle

Comment: @vijaychaudhary I know how to create gradient drawable. The problem is that `windowSplashScreenBackground` accept only colors. That\`s why it\`s not working with drawable

Comment: Refer this link: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/modern-splash-screen-in-android-9c804903c7c9

Comment: @vijaychaudhary I saw this article. It\`s helpful article but there is no answer to my question

Comment: I think it\`s not  possible make gradient background and animated logo only using new Splash screen API. Need to resort to old proven methods

Comment: @Almaz_KhR then you can't target android 12

Comment: Any updates here? Same problem.

Comment: @SharpSteelSoftware Nothing. Problem is actual

Comment: i am wondering if we could have drawable images as a background not only gradient colors as the icon position must be dynamic this api is not fine

Comment: You can create a .png image with the gradient that you want, and then use it as a in the `windowSplashScreenBackground` field. It is going to be a drawable as well, but for some reason when you use a .png drawable in the field it works(unlike with the same drawable as a .xml file).

Comment: @Almaz_KhR did you figure our a solution?

Comment: Everything is moving towards becoming more advanced, but Google has decided to restrict developers instead of progressing. Stupid. Its reaction after this restriction:   

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is - no, you can't use any drawable in  windowSplashScreenBackground. Only regular hex color. That's limitation of new splash screen api. I have used and deeply investigated this version on June 1, 2022:

```
"androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-rc01"
```

if you'll use this property like this, or will remove it at all -- you'll receive as a result - default system color on background or totaly black screen on API level < 31.

```
<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@null</item>
<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/some_custom_splash_background</item>
```

The same story with icon property: if it is NULL -- then default app icon will be shown (but on android api < 31 - it will be even worse), if icon has wrong sizes - it will be sqeezed to fixed sizes and circle shape. If you'll remove that property at all - it will use default app icon. You can't run away from icon in the center of the screen. Maby just try to make such icon with transparent color -- I think it can help, but didn't tried by myself.

```
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@null</item>
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
```

Other properties like: windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor, windowSplashScreenBrandingImage - are only available for API version 31+.

What I find out as workaround: it's to use new approach of SplashScreenAPI on Android 12+, and old one -- on all older versions. I have one MainActivity - and all of my screens are fragments. I have two style.xml files: res/values/style.xml and res-v31/values/style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.App.NewSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#24a0d1</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">#f0e067</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/brand_logo</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and this is style.xml -- for all previous android versions:

```
<style name="Theme.App.NewSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MyAppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

And then in MainActivity's onCreate method I just do check for Android API version. That's it.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31){
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen() //init new splash screen api for Android 12+
    } else{
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyAppTheme) //else use old approach
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
```

and in AndroidManifest use new theme, which has the same name, but is different for different android versions:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.NewSplashScreenTheme">
```

But as for me - I highly recommend to use only one approach: new splash screen api or the old one. Because who knows how it will be behaving in future versions.

Also, I can recommend some links to read, which helped me to investigate it faster:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate

https://www.raywenderlich.com/32555180-splash-screen-tutorial-for-android
https://itnext.io/a-comprehensive-guide-to-android-12s-splash-screen-api-644609c811fa
https://habr.com/ru/post/648535/
https://medium.com/viithiisys/android-perfect-way-to-create-splash-screen-ca3c5bee137f
https://proandroiddev.com/splash-screen-android-12-173c3c641671
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/modern-splash-screen-in-android-9c804903c7c9

Comment: For those of you who's wondering the complete old ways implementation, you can follow this article https://medium.com/geekculture/implementing-the-perfect-splash-screen-in-android-295de045a8dc

Answer (score 6):

I had this discussion (on Slack group 'Android Developers France') with a Google engineer working on the Android framework. He told me this is not a limitation but by design. Google designers wanted to unify the design and the transition between the OS and the application.

(here is the screenshot of his answer -in french- https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaiwy.jpg)

He also stated that we could still code a custom animation with the splash screen to fade in the gradient tho.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can only animate the logo though, not the background.