# Ionic Capacitor Android 12 Splash screen: use bitmap image

Tags: android, ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor

In previous versions of Capacitor, the splash screen on Android was an image that was specified in splash.png. I have recently upgraded to Capacitor 4 and changed the target SDK version to 32. From what I have read, the Android 12 Splash screen API now uses your App Icon as a splash screen, and you may customize the background color, animations, etc.

Is there any way to use the old behavior, I.e. Show a custom image as a splash screen?

Please note I am not an android developer and have only used Ionic/Capacitor to create apps, thanks.

Update: I don't think this is currently possible. See:

[Android 12 custom splash screen with background image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70898354/4553162)

[Android 12 Splash Screen API customization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69005715/4553162)

Comment: I currently have the same issue, I tryed with [capacitor-assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/assets) and [cordova-res](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-res).

Notice: now cordova-res github redirect to capacitor-assets

Comment: I have the same issue too.