How to create a solid colour Android launcher screen?
Before my blank activity is active, the launcher screen very briefly appears. It's the default android icon.
I want to change this to a solid colour. I'm targeting android SDK 33. I understand things changed in the last couple of android versions.
Here's my AndroidManifest.xml. I've tried setting windowBackground and windowSplashScreenBackground on both the activity and application to no avail.
I explicitly want to set this solid colour launcher screen in the AndroidManifest.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    package="com.example"  
    android:versionCode="1"  
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk  
        android:minSdkVersion="33"  
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application
        android:windowBackground="#000000"
        android:windowSplashScreenBackground="#000000"
        android:label="MyApp">
        <activity  
            android:name=".MyActivity"  
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowBackground="#000000"
            android:windowSplashScreenBackground="#000000"
            android:label="Empty Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

I have a lead regarding https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/ActivityOptions.html?hl=en#setSplashScreenStyle(kotlin.Int). However to use ActivityOptions I need to launch an activity and the system is launching my activity, so I'm unsure if this is a dead-end or not.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/68711324/24823442
